# Connecting .accdb access database to QGIS

Tags: ms-access, qgis

I am trying to link an access database that is .accdb not .mdb . What do I need to do? where am I going wrong?

I have already tried to create it under the ODBC data source admin 32-bit (System DSN) tab. I selected the Driver - Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb) Data source name = Faunafile and selected the database which I have saved in my c drive. System database is None.

The in QGIs I click on "add vector". click database. in type I choose ESRI Personal GeoDatabase and under connections click New.

Type = ESRI Personal Geodatabase. Name is Faunafile and Database = Faunafile. Then when I try to test connect it comes up with an error message.

This is the error message I get:

Connection failed - Check settings and try again.

Extended error information:
Unable to initialize ODBC connection to DSN for Faunafile,
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're using QGis 64-bits. Try to uninstall it and install QGis 32-bits. I had the same problem and now it works.